# Is there a list or way to find all of the fields that have different names, but contain the same data?

Tags: peoplesoft

For example, EMPLID also being stored as COMMON_ID. I know that Term (STRM) also is stored in different tables as something else.

I'm just curious if there's a list of all this by table.field somewhere? Or, if there's a way within SQL or App Designer to extract that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any delivered way to do this.

The closest I can think of is to query a table like PSDBFIELD looking for fields whose metadata matches EMPLID.

e.g. fields with length 11, type string, formatting uppercase

Answer (score 0):

I wrote scripts to do this a while back that are available on GitHub.  There is a PL/SQL version for Oracle DBs and an SQR version. It basically looks for all fields that could contain the data value being searched and queries each table to see if the value exists. It can take a while, but we have used it several times successfully.

https://github.com/otherted/findfieldvalue

The main driver is, of course, selecting table and field names...

```
SELECT 
     RF.RECNAME
   , RF.FIELDNAME
   , RD.SQLTABLENAME
   , F.FIELDTYPE
   FROM SYSADM.PSRECFIELDDB RF, SYSADM.PSRECDEFN RD, SYSADM.PSDBFIELD F
   WHERE RF.FIELDNAME LIKE UPPER(:fieldnamein)
   AND RD.RECNAME = RF.RECNAME
   AND RD.RECTYPE = 0  -- ONLY CHECK SQL TABLES
   AND RF.FIELDNAME = F.FIELDNAME
   AND F.FIELDTYPE LIKE :fieldtypein
   AND F.FIELDTYPE <> 8  -- exclue IMAGE fields which are binary BLOB
   AND (((F.LENGTH + F.DECIMALPOS + 2) >= length(:fieldvaluein)) 
        OR (F.LENGTH = 0))
   ORDER BY RF.RECNAME, RF.FIELDNAME;
```

Then for each table/field try to find the value...

```
 'SELECT UPPER(' || o_realfldname || '), COUNT(*) ' ||
      'FROM SYSADM.' || o_realrecname || ' A ' ||
      'WHERE UPPER(' || o_realfldname || ') LIKE :1 '  ||
      'GROUP BY UPPER(' || o_realfldname || ') ';
```